# UnicodeEncodeError when using line_profiler

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, line-profiler

I am learning python and try to analyze the code performance by line. I installed line_profiler but it always showed the

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 30-31: character maps to undefined

I tried to run chcp 65001 which didn't work.

```
import cgi
import time
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

def test2():
    print('hello!test2()')

def test1():
    html='''<script>alert("you are a good boy!&I like you")</scrpit>'''
    test2()
    escape_html=cgi.escape(html)
    for item in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
    print(escape_html)

if __name__=='__main__':
    lp=LineProfiler()
    lp.add_function(test2)
    lp_wrap=lp(test1)
    lp_wrap()
    lp.print_stats()
```

The results:

> hello!test2()
>
> C:\OneDrive\u684c\u9762\linecheck.py:91: DeprecationWarning: cgi.escape is deprecated, use html.escape instead  escape_html=cgi.escape(html)
>
> <script>alert("you are a good boy!&I like you")</scrpit>
>   Timer unit: 5.14057e-07 s
>
> Total time: 2.6731e-05 s
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\OneDrive\u684c\u9762\linecheck.py", line 101, in
>
> lp.print_stats()
>
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\line_profiler.py", line 139, in print_stats
>
> show_text(lstats.timings, lstats.unit, output_unit=output_unit, stream=stream, stripzeros=stripzeros)
>
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\line_profiler.py", line 261, in show_text
>
> output_unit=output_unit, stream=stream, stripzeros=stripzeros)
>
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\line_profiler.py", line 210, in show_func
>
> stream.write("File: %s\n" % filename)
>
> File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 30-31: character maps to 
>   [Finished in 5.8s]

Comment: Which line causes the error? Maybe you should include the full traceback.

Comment: thank you for pointing out.